# Ping multiple IP addresses and set the timer to re-ping

Tags: c#

I have code below to ping the IP address, but when I run this code, it's not running because there is no update into the database.

Here is the `Start` code:

```
protected void Start()
{
    string ip_STCKL = "*.*.10.";
    string ip_STCKCH = "*.*.128.";

    for (int ipCount = ip_addr; ipCount < 195; ipCount++)
    {
        string ip = ip_STCKL + ipCount.ToString();

        string loopIp = ip;
        WaitCallback func = delegate(object state)
        {
            if (PingIP(loopIp))
            {
                UpdateStatusKL(loopIp, true);
                Console.WriteLine("Ping Success");
            }
            else
            {
                loopIp = ip_STCKCH + ipCount.ToString();
                if (PingIP(loopIp))
                {
                    UpdateStatusKL(loopIp, true);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Ping Success");
                }
                else
                {
                    UpdateStatusKL(loopIp, false);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Ping Failed");
                }
            }
        };
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(func);
        //ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads;
    }

    //Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This is the ping function to get the status:

```
public static bool PingIP(string IP)
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(IP);

        if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            result = true;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

After get the status, update into the database:

```
public void UpdateStatusKL(string IP, bool Status)
{

    string New_Status = "";

    if (Status)
    {
        New_Status = "REACHABLE";
    }
    else
    {
        New_Status = "UNREACHABLEE";
    }


    //Declare the connection object
    OracleConnection Conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=COMMSERVERKL;User
    Id=mt_mon;Password=butus123");

    //Make the connection
    Conn.Open();

    //Define you query
    string sql = "UPDATE BalaiConnectionStatus SET Balai_Status = :pstatus,
    Timestamp = :pTime WHERE IP_STCKL = :pIP OR IP_STCKCH = :pIP";
    //Declare the Command
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, Conn);

    //Add the parameters needed for the SQL query
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("pstatus", OracleType.VarChar).Value = New_Status;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pTime", OracleType.VarChar).Value =
    DateTime.Now.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pIP", OracleType.VarChar).Value = IP;


    //Execute the query

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Conn.Close();
}
```

Every 15 minutes when the timer trigger, it will call the `Start` function to start pinging all the IP addresses again:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ip_addr = 10;
    Start();
}
```

What is the problem with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: What does `ExecuteNonQuery` returns ?

Comment: try changing your `cmd.Parameters.Add to cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` instead also what does the initial update query yield if anything at all..?

Comment: Did you unit test individual methods on their own to ensure they work before tackling the whole application? Just as a remark, why not storing a status bit instead of whole string in the database?

Comment: Ofiris, thanks for your reply. ExecuteNonQuery return 0.

Comment: DJ KRAZE, the result still same. No update.

Comment: Tarik, when I comment out WaitCallbackFunc and ThreadPool, its working but I want to use thread pool.